# How to notify about the push notification when screen is locked?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hello Everyone,
                I am new to android development and currently working on google cloud messaging everything is working fine but the problem is that i am not able to get the notification icon and color defined by application on lock screen like other application gives like what's app green color and icon displayed on locked screen similarly gmail red color and icon displayed on home screen so can anyone tell me how to achieve it i am very thankful to you.

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setColor(
                        getResources().getColor(
                                R.color.abc_primary_text_material_dark))
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setContentInfo("hi")
                .setTicker("hi")
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setLights(0x0000FF, 1000, 4000)
                ;

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        WakeLock wakeLock = pm
                .newWakeLock(
                        (PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
                                | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP),
                        "TAG");
        wakeLock.acquire(15000);
        // Settings.System.putString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
        // Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED, "hi");

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your attempted code.

Comment: Even lights are not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Notification notif = new Notification(
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, message,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        notif.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, WelcomeActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it's the icon set through `setSmallIcon`. The value `R.drawable.ic_launcher` in the code refers to an image in the *res/drawable* directory of your Android project. You can change it to `R.drawable.<name of the icon you want to use>`, as long as that image has been placed in the drawable folder.